# Is there a drawback to having many objective-c categories?

Tags: objective-c, premature-optimization, objective-c-category

We have some code in objective-c categories which we want to share between projects.  There are (at least) two approaches we can take:

1. Put them in one category per class, called something like `UIView+SGBExtensions`
2. Put then in a number of different categories by use, e.g. `UIView+SGBLayout`, `UIView+SGBDrawing`, etc..

My instinct is to go with the latter, as it will be more descriptive and we can cherry-pick.  However, most of our apps will include most of the shared code, so I'm a little concerned that having a lot of categories might impact performance or app size. Is there a drawback to having many objective-c categories?

Answer (score 3):

I think the difference would be negligible. During loading, it may involve more steps to iterate over the categories and add their methods, rather than adding methods from a single category.  Likewise, if the categories have `+load` methods, that's several method calls rather than a single one.  Like I said, negligible.

Answer (score 2):

My instinct is the same as yours.  Segregating the code out your way is more maintainable.

I don't think you should worry about size and performance until your application has been demonstrated to have a problem in those respects.  Even then, don't assume, measure.  For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure that the performance and size impact will be close to zero.